Problems with the table component in Jasper report
When the text is too long in one of the table columns and you move to the next page, it does not fill the other cells. In other words, the correct thing to expect is that the lines in the other cells would be filled, but that does not happen
and the Data Overflows property is not an option.
Is there an option to solve this?
The image shows what is happening to me
enter image description here
Is there a way to complete the other cells when this happens?
An alternative would be to use lists but it is the same
